# Movie about underground creatures or monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I am looking for this movie about underground creatures in a village and I think they were also looking for their unknown prince. They begun sucking kids from the underground and the ending reveals the prince and then he slit the boy’s wrist surrounded with his children which are the monster.

Horror American movie, not sure the year though probably late 90’s or early 2000. The prince reminds me of the crow or edward scissor hands.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Animated? Live action? When would it have been made, and in which language?

Comment: Its a horror movie, i just remembered the ending, a boy was drag from the underground and his wrist was cut by the so called prince of the creatures. The prince kind of reminded me like the crow or edward scissor hands.